# Finding a closed-form solution for the following fixed point algorithm,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, fixed-point-theorems

\begin{equation}
X^{(t)}=\frac{SK}{\bigg(\frac{ZK}{(1+X^{(t-1)})} +\frac{Y(RK+Y)}{R^{2}}\bigg)}\
\end{equation}
For $ \text{t}=1,2,...$,

where the initial value $X^{(t-1)}={R}$

Please, any help or any hint to find the solution closed-form.

Comment: Closed form for the limit or for the sequence?

Comment: Dear Martin, Thank you very much for your help. In fact, it is the limit since  $X=\lim_{t\to\infty } X^{(t)}$

Comment: Then $X$ is simply the solution of a quadratic equation.

Comment: So what is the final results should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite
$$
X^{(t)} = \frac{SK}{\frac{ZK}{1 + X^{(t-1)}} +\frac{Y(RK+Y)}{R^2}} =
\frac{A}{\frac{B}{1 + X^{(t-1)}} + C}.
$$
Take limit
$$X = \frac{A}{\frac{B}{1 + X} + C}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$CX^2 + (B + C - A)X - A = 0.$$
with solutions
$$X = {A-B-C\pm{\sqrt{C^2+\left(2\,B+2\,A\right)C+B^2-2AB+A^2}}\over{2C}}.$$

Comment: Great! Correct. Thank you very much, dear.